# How to calculate how many elements which contain a certain string in 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, sum, checksum

I have a 2D array like this:

```
[[aaa-1-2,
  aaa-3-4,
  bbb-y-t,
  aaa-5-t],
[bbb-1-2,
  dfs-3-4,
  bbb-a-9,
  yui-5-t]]
```

I want to write a function or something to get the sum of the elements which contain 'aaa' (in `[aaa-1-2, aaa-3-4, bbb-y-t, aaa-5-t]`), and the sum of 'bbb' in `[bbb-1-2, dfs-3-4, bbb-a-9, yui-5-t]`.

In this example, the sum should be `3+2=5`, I only know how to calculate the sum of the exact same elements between two arrays, but not sure how to solve this, can someone help me with this? thanks.

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just calculate each total separately, then add them together. You say you know how to do the first part.

Comment: Is there something more complicated about it, like the search strings are dynamic, or the number of alements in the top-level array is variable?

Comment: I have no idea how you get 3+2 = 5 in the first place or understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish.  Please provide more details.

Comment: HI @dreamzboy in the first 1D array, there are three elements that contain 'aaa', in the second 1D array, there are two elements that contain 'bbb'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general solution where you have n prefixes corresponding to n sublists, you can use `enumerate` to figure out which sublist you are in and lookup the appropriate prefix to use, then sum the tests:

```
l = [["aaa-1-2", "aaa-3-4","bbb-y-t","aaa-5-t"],
     ["bbb-1-2", "dfs-3-4", "bbb-a-9","yui-5-t"]]

prefix = ['aaa', 'bbb']    
sum(prefix[i] in s for i, sub in enumerate(l) for s in sub)

# 5
```

If you have more sublists and more stings you can just add to the prefix list.